# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null console sees the value correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a webpage where you can sign in an make an account and so on. However when I try to portray the users information I get the error 'Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'

When I print the value in the console using:

```
console.log(temp.gender);
```

it properly displays the value female. And this is just the row above the non functioning line of code which is:

```
document.getElementById("account_gender").innerHTML = temp.gender;
```

I get the error mentioned above. The entire function is activated in the window.onload so the DOM tree should be completed. And all the other values seem to work.

I should mention that the gender is selected via an option input. I have tried to extract the value in different ways but with the same result. So for now it is:

```
gender = document.getElementById("signupgender").value;
```

When the user signs up.

Code for the div in HTML

```
<div>
    <h3> My information </h3>
    <div id="account_info"><label>Email: </label><div id="account_mail"></div></div>
    <div id="account_info"><label>Name: </label><div id="account_firstname"></div></div>
    <div id="account_info"><label>Gender: </label><div id="account_gender"></div></div>
    <div id="account_info"><label>City: </label><div id="account_city"></div></div>
    <div id="account_info"><label>Country: </label><div id="account_country"></div></div>
</div>
```

Code for loading the data into the divs in JS

```
temp = serverstub.getUserDataByToken(token).data;

console.log(temp.gender);

document.getElementById("account_mail").innerHTML = temp.email;
document.getElementById("account_firstname").innerHTML = temp.firstname + " " + temp.familyname;
document.getElementById("account_gender").innerHTML = temp.gender;
document.getElementById("account_city").innerHTML = temp.city;
document.getElementById("account_country").innerHTML = temp.country;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have element with id `account_gender`?

Comment: The problem is not with the *value* but with your dom element reference. Check what Satpal is asking.

Comment: Yes the element name is correct, I have copy pasted the div id just to be certain.

Comment: try document.getElementByName("account_gender").innerHTML = temp.gender;

Comment: Either there is no component with id as 'account_gender' or it is not rendered in DOM. You can post your code so that  we can figure out.

Comment: Please post your HTML code about the div

Comment: Added the code now. getElementsByName solves the error but still does not display the gender.

Comment: check if document.getElementById("account_gender") is not null. make sure you add your <script> tag at the bottom of your page. Just before </body>

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine ..
Check this [fiddle][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/udwwg31t/2/.

There may be some problem with response.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your comment that it is the name and not ID. try following

```
document.getElementsByName("account_gender")[0].innerHTML = temp.gender;
```

check if document.getElementById("account_gender") is not null. make sure you add your  tag at the bottom of your page. Just before 
To make sure your all elements are loaded when you run the script. try following method to debug.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    alert(document.getElementById("account_gender"));
}, false);
```